# What is the meaning of tag "datasourcecontrol"?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

Tag [datasourcecontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datasourcecontrol) has no tag description ("guidance") and it seems the name is confusing some people. It appears to get used for a mix of version-control and data-related GUI control questions.

Those which were clearly about [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control) I have just retagged to that and removed [datasourcecontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datasourcecontrol). Many of them already had [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control) anyway.

The remainder *mostly* seem to be about GUI controls, but I'm not familiar enough with the specific cases its being used for to know what tag guidance to write (or even if this tag should continue to exist). But I think even a basic description from someone knowledgeable would help focus this tag so that its useful.

Or, if people think we should just delete it, fine with me.

Comment: Having touched C# before, I believe it's referring to the [`DataSourceControl` class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datasourcecontrol?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: How am I supposed to interpret a downvote on this?

Comment: You might want to add the [support] tag to your question

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs I don't know, but meta votes don't really affect your reputation, and there will always be people who disagree. Perhaps someone disagrees with you, and they think the tag should stay like that. (ofc I agree that some retagging and guidance editing is in place).

Comment: @10Rep thanks, I wasn't worried about rep, genuinely had no idea what there was to disagree with.

Comment: I, for one, think that [datasourcecontrol] should be deleted. It wouldn't cause much harm as there are only 7 questions with that tag.

Comment: Agree with @AndrewT. this is a specific reference to issues when using the `DataSourceControl` in ASP.Net. All of the current questions with that tag match the use case and I would probably feel inclined to create such a tag myself if I were to post a similar question and the tag did not already exist. It is my interpretation that this is a valid use for tags, especially given that there are likely many questions that could be tagged with this and it is a specialised area that some members might take an active interest in.

Comment: In that case, I now question if it was appropriate for this tag to be removed from other questions, It might be, but by not understanding the tag, that is when the question should have been raised, not after removing questions that may have had relevance. All we need here is the Tag wiki to be completed...

Comment: Who still uses [ASP.Net WebForms Data Source Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/moving-to-aspnet-20/data-source-controls) (harking back to ASP.Net 2.0)?

Comment: Use google first, shows it is a [webforms] topic.  Pretty antiquated, but stunningly still gets 93 questions/month.   Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Given the answer by someone more knowledgeable than myself about the topic area, I'm withdrawing my offer to remove the [tag:datasourcecontrol] tag (at 9 of the 10 votes I said I'd take as a threshold).

Answer (score 11):

From the remaining questions tagged with [[datasourcecontrol]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datasourcecontrol/info) it is clear that this tag relates to the ASP.Net [DataSourceControl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datasourcecontrol?view=netframework-4.8).

I have posted a suggested wiki edit and Tag info:

> For questions specifically involving the ASP.Net DataSourceControl for managing data bindings of record sets in Web Forms.

There is one question tagged with [[.net-datasourcecontrol]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-datasourcecontrol) which is clearly the same thing, so I guess these two tags should be merged, the question is which one is more appropriate to remain as the tag, as this is a platform specific control, I now feel that [.net-databasourcecontrol] is probably more appropriate.

Comment: The one question tagged [tag:.net-datasourcecontrol] appears to have been retagged with just [tag:datasourcecontrol] as there are now 8 questions with the simpler tag.  I think that's probably a mistake.  It would likely have been better to retag with the [tag:.net-datasourcecontrol] tag, and put the Tag Wiki information into that tag.

Comment: thanks @JonathanLeffler I agree and have made the edits, just waiting for the tag edit to be approved

Comment: Someone has burninated it. I approved your tag edits, but next time please include usage guidance (I edited it in)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I created that tag on purpose, datasourcecontrol is a disaster waiting to happen. .net-datasourcecontrol is more descriptive and not a potential train wreck.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if we could edit the tag? Or can mods do that perhaps?